# Question about multiple 'catch'

Tags: java, exception

Can anyone tell me why the output of this class is  'xa'?

why the other exception(RuntimeException and Exception ) won't be caught?

```
public class Tree {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        try
        {
            throw new NullPointerException(new Exception().toString());
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e)
        {
            System.out.print("x");
        }
        catch (RuntimeException e)
        {
            System.out.print("y");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.print("z");   
        }        
        finally{System.out.println("a");}
    }
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't catch NullPointerException

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only exception thrown is the one right next to the throw statement. The other is created but not thrown. It is not possible to throw two exceptions simultaneously.

Typically when an exception is passed in the constructor of another exception it is to indicate that the that exception is the cause of this one. However, the only exception actually being thrown is the one next to the throw statement.

In this case NullPointerException does not support an Exception in its constructor because it is not caused by other exceptions, it is caused by null references. In other cases it is because exception chaining was not introduced in Java until 1.4, so some legacy exception classes didn't get retro-fitted with new constructors. In that case you can use the `initCause(Throwable)` method to do what the constructor would have done.

Answer (score 16):

#### Just because an exception is created, doesn't mean it's thrown

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Exception();
    System.out.println("Yippee!!");
    // prints "Yippee!!"
}
```

#### Just because there's a `catch` clause, doesn't mean something was caught

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {
        System.out.println("No math for me!");
    } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        System.out.println("Math was wronged!");
    } // prints "No math for me!"
}
```

#### Exception can be thrown during the creation of another exception

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        throw new NullPointerException(args[-1]);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println("Ooops!");
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println("Ooh lala!!");           
    } // prints "Ooh lala!!"
}
```

#### You can only `catch` things thrown from where your `try` is

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {
        args[-1] = null;
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println("Gotcha!");
        args[1/0] = null;
    } catch (ArithmeticException e) {           
        System.out.println("You missed me!");
    } // prints "Gotcha!"
} // Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
```

#### Practically under "all" circumstances, `finally` is always executed

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        throw new Exception();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Oops!");
        args[-1] = null;
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Yay!");
    } // prints "Oops!", "Yay!",
} // Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
```

#### Abrupt completion of `finally` trumps abrupt completion of `try/catch`

```
static String greetings() {
    try {
        return "No mood!";
    } finally {
        return "Hey buddy!";
    }
}   
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(greetings()); // prints "Hey buddy!"
    try {
        args[-1] = null;
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        throw new Exception("Catch me if you can!");
    } finally {
        throw new Exception("Yoink!");
    }
} // Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Yoink!
```

Comment: You've danced all around it, but none of these examples actually answers the question.

Answer (score 7):

The `x` is printed by the first `catch` block (the `NullPointerException`).

The `a` is printed by the `finally` block.

The `finally` block is always executed whether there was exception thrown or not.

EDIT:

Only one `catch` block will be executed. In your case, since `NullPointerException` extends `RuntimeException` extends `Exception`, the first `catch` block that accepts these Exceptions will handle the exception.

On a side note: You normally shouldn't be catching a `NullPointerException`. See this [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html) from the Sun website.

Answer (score 6):

Only the first catch block that matches the type of exception thrown will be executed.  So even though `NullPointerException` is a `RuntimeException` and an `Exception`, it has already been caught before those blocks.

If you reverse the order of the catch blocks, then the `Exception` block will execute.  (This is not recommended, though.  You should always put your catch blocks in the order of most specific to least specific, as you have in the example.)

Comment: This is the most appropriate answer to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Here, you throw a NullPointerException in the try block, and so it will be caught in the first catch block that applies. Once it's caught, it's caught.

Answer (score 2):

Java handles an Exception with the *first* catch block that matches the Exception thrown. So since the exception thrown is a `NullPointerException`, it's caught by the first catch block and the rest are ignored. The `finally` block always executes (unless you terminate abnormally e.g. System.exit).

So you get "x" output from the NullPointerException catch block, and "a" is output from the finally block.

Answer (score 0):

A NullPointerException was thrown and it was handled and printed "x" in the console.

Then the finally statement is executed and printed "a" to the console and therefore you got the "xa".

Answer (score 0):

The way try/catch works is as follow:

1. The body code is executed until its end, or until an exception is thrown;
2. If an exception is thrown and there is a matching catch, the code for the matching catch clause is executed;
3. The **finally** code **is always executed, whether or not an exception was thrown, and whether or not it was caught**

Answer (score 0):

Because you are only throwing one exception. You can create exceptions all you like, but unless you throw them they will never be caught. You never throw the generic Exception, so it can never be caught.

And by the way, there's no way to throw two exceptions at the same time. If you write:

```
try
{
    throw new Exception();
    throw new NullPointerException();
}
catch (NullPointerException e)
{
  System.out.printlne("first");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  System.ot.println("second");
}
```

The compiler will just kick you out because the second throw is unreachable code. An exception is like a GOTO.